# Angular5 @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to component Service to Target

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using a [@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) component to make a easy scroll to.

I have create a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qonsQh6W8MFwX2WsKzDh?p=preview) with 2 buttom:

1. one use directive and work fine
2. one use a service to target but not scroll (what's wrong?)

   ```
   public triggerScrollTo() {

   const config: ScrollToConfigOptions = {
   container: 'custom-container',
   target: 'destination'
   };

   this._scrollToService.scrollTo(config);
   }
   ```

Comment: It seems, removing the `container: 'custom-container'` from the `const config: ScrollToConfigOptions` allows the scroll to work.